# Write a shell script to calculate the size of each project in a directory?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to write a shell script to calculate how much space each project folder is occupying on my server, suppose i have a Home folder in which numerous project folders are there, rather than writing `du -sh "project name"` every time want it to calculate it correspondingly in one file like :

```
ABC 40 Gb
XYZ 60 GB
```

Comment: i tried the above command, but it is quite time consuming so wanted to go ahead with script. Any ideas, please share.

Comment: So you basically have a bunch of folders and want a command/script to find sizes for all such folders in one-shot?

Comment: perfect! this my requirement..due to the huge size of projects, could not calculate in one go. so wanted a command or script to do that.

Comment: I believe you can use `ncdu` package runned at `/home/` directory. It will count all nested directories only once. Then it will show you console-window application where you can explore nested folders.

Comment: Anything needs to be specified in curly braces {}
and on "/your/path" i need to specify my home folder path..
Let me know if am correct.

Comment: @AnishSethi: You don't have to add anything in `{}`, refer my update with a detailed explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `find` command would suffice:-

```
find /your/path -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec du -sh "{}" \;
```

Refer this [`man find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) page to see how the options are used.

To summarize the options:-

- `-type d` & `-maxdepth 1` looks for only folders from the path mentioned which in your case `/your/path` at one folder level
- Thanks to [`frist's`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5648958/frist) suggestion below adding the `-mindepth 1` flag lets you avoid re-calculating the size of all the folders combined.
- `-exec` runs the `du -sh` command on each of the directory returned by `find`. Each of the directory is identified by `{}`, and double-quotes are added to preserve the original directory name
- `\;` runs the command once for each directory.

Sample output:-

```
4.0K ./myfolder
24K  ./destfolder
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
du -sh project1 project2 project3
```

Comment: Do you think it is possible to get the size without consuming time?

Comment: @AnishSethi if you want to calculate the summary size of the folder, the only way to do that is recursively iterate by each nested `file/folder`. So you will have to wait anyway. The other approach is to use file-system accounting feature (a part of quota feature), but you will have to create each project folder on behalf of separate user.

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont simply do

```
du -hs /path/to/projects/dir/*
```

EDIT: Without du command

```
for line in `ls /path/to/your/project/dir/`; do echo $line && find $line -type f -printf '%s\n' | awk '{ total += $1 }; END { print total }'; done
```

Comment: Yep, but how do u want to check the file size without checking the filesize of each on?

Comment: Did you hear about filesystem quotas?